# Inoperative p:commandLink when using #{param} in rendered attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, param, commandlink, rendered-attribute

I have a page displaying some profile, so it's URL `../faces/savedProfile.xhtml?profileId=1234`.

On that page I have p:pane containing a few p:commandLink components, something like this:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{profileController.canViewProfile}">
...
    <p:commandLink 
        id="duplicateLink"
        value="Duplicate"
        action="#{profileController.duplicateProfile}"/>
...
</p:panel>
```

It works.
Now I want to add another rendering condition:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{profileController.canViewProfile
        and param['profileId'] != null}">
...
    <p:commandLink 
        id="duplicateLink"
        value="Duplicate"
        action="#{profileController.duplicateProfile}"/>
...
</p:panel>
```

The p:commandLink is displayed, but it is not active. It seems that action method is not being invoked on click.
Why would that additional rendering condition kill the commandLink?

Comment: Can you add the `<h:messages>` somewhere on the page ? I believe the JSF validation phase has not passed for some reason.

Comment: Please refer to [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656/1065197) and see the most common reasons that can cause your `UICommand` to fail. After that, check the generated HTML in order to see if you have nested forms or another HTML problem. Note that with current info is hard to understand a possible cause of your exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `rendered` attribute is not only evaluated during the HTTP request which returns the page with the command link, but it's also evaluated during the HTTP request initiated by the command link. Apparently you're not retaining the request parameter during that HTTP request which causes that the `rendered` attribute evaluates `false` and thus the clicked command link cannot be idenfified and hence its action event will never be queued.

This matches point 5 of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183).

The solution in your case is to add `<f:param>` to retain the request parameter:

```
<p:commandLink ...>
    <f:param name="profileId" value="#{param.profileId}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, better use `empty` instead of `!= null` which will then also cover empty strings:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{profileController.canViewProfile and not empty param.profileId}">
```

Or much better, use `<f:viewParam>` in combination with a view scoped bean (and a `Profile` converter):

```
<f:viewParam name="profileId" value="#{profileController.profile}" />
```

with

```
<p:panel rendered="#{profileController.canViewProfile and not empty profileController.profile}">
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/)

Comment: I've added <f:param> and it works like a charm. But since I'll have other commandLink(s) on that page, using <f:viewParam> helps even more. Thanks!